# How would you say: "But only X years ago, in month Z of Year Y ..." in Taiwan

Tags: grammar, taiwan

In Mandarin, how would you say:

```
But only X years ago, in month Z of Year Y ...
```

For example.

```
Now, they say the sun is red.
But only two years ago, in September 2015, they said the sun was blue.
```

Please note that I would like to convey the meaning of "**on the contrary (of the situation earlier), now the opposite situation ...**". If possible, I am looking to say so as one would say it in Taiwan, not as one would say it in China.

Please answer using traditional characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chinese, we use 'Y-M-D' format for stating date.

> "But only two years ago" - "祗不過兩年前"

~

> "in September 2015" - "在二零一五年九月" (In Chinese, we state year before month)

or

"**在** 2015 年 **的**九月" - "**in** September **of** 2015

*Emphasize the month if it is an important information. For example, September is the end of summer holiday*

Comment: Please note that, right now, your answer includes 两 (simplified), whereas the traditional form is the slightly different 兩.